# Select one to many relation table in query set django

Tags: django-rest-framework, one-to-many, django-rest-viewsets

I would like to select one to many table relation in query set.I have two model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    postid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'post'

class Images(models.Model):
    postid = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_to, blank=True)
```

In `list` method of Post `viewset`, I would like to select format like=>

```
          {
            "postid": 1,
            "images":[
                image:"Image Result"
            ]
          }
```

Here is Post `viewset` =>

```
def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.queryset
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        for post in self.queryset:
            img = Images.objects.all().filter(postid=post.postid)

        serializer = PostSerializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

How to insert this img result to post?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [RelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) documentation.  Something like:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['postid', 'images']
```

This will give you a string representation of the Image, but you can look at other Relationship fields in the documentation to customise the JSON representation of the image.

Doing it like this will likely mean you don't need to override `list()` in the viewset as well.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I solved this by using a nested relationship.[https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships]